# How to output spark data to a csv file with separate columns?

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My code 1st extracts data using a regex and writes that data to a text file (string format). 
I then tried creating a dataframe out of the contents in the text file so that i can have separate columns which led to an error. (Writing it to a csv file writes the entire thing into just one column).

```
with open("C:\\Sample logs\\dataframe.txt",'a') as f:
    f.write(str(time))
    f.write(" ")
    f.write(qtype)
    f.write(" ")
    f.write(rtype)
    f.write(" ")
    f.write(domain)
    f.write("\n")
 new = sc.textFile("C:\\Sample logs\\dataframe.txt").cache() # cause df requires an rdd
 lines1 = new.map(lambda x: (x, ))
 df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(lines1)
```

But i get the following error:

> TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: type 'unicode'

I tried some other ways but didn't help. All that I want to do is that after performing write operation, i want to create a dataframe that has separate columns in order to use groupBy().

The input in the text file:

```
1472128348.0 HTTP - tr.vwt.gsf.asfh
1472237494.63 HTTP - tr.sdf.sff.sdfg
1473297794.26 HTTP - tr.asfr.gdfg.sdf
1474589345.0 HTTP - tr.sdgf.gdfg.gdfg
1472038475.0 HTTP - tr.sdf.csgn.sdf
```

Expected output in csv format:

> The same thing as above but separated into columns so i can perform
>   groupby operations.

Comment: Could you please do `lines1.take(1)`

Comment: please give example for input data, and expected dataframe structure

Comment: Is there a [`saveAsTextFile`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.saveAsTextFile) method for [`DataFrame`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame) class too? What is your spark version?

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto: It returns the 1st line from the input

Comment: @Yaron: I've added it to the question

Comment: @Ajeets: It will throw an error later for sure if the previous line passes. Just added it to know the errors.

Comment: @kaks What's the exact problem? `How to save in csv?` or `TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: type 'unicode'`? And by looking at your input file and the steps, there seems to be no `TypeError` problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to replace "space separated words" into a list of words you'll need to replace:

```
lines1 = new.map(lambda x: (x, ))
```

with

```
 lines1 = new.map(lambda line: line.split(' '))
```

I tried it on my machine, and after executing the following

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(lines1)
```

A new DF was created:

```
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _4: string (nullable = true)

df.show()
+-------------+----+---+-----------------+
|           _1|  _2| _3|               _4|
+-------------+----+---+-----------------+
| 1472128348.0|HTTP|  -|  tr.vwt.gsf.asfh|
|1472237494.63|HTTP|  -|  tr.sdf.sff.sdfg|
|1473297794.26|HTTP|  -| tr.asfr.gdfg.sdf|
| 1474589345.0|HTTP|  -|tr.sdgf.gdfg.gdfg|
| 1472038475.0|HTTP|  -|  tr.sdf.csgn.sdf|
+-------------+----+---+-----------------+
```

You can execute groupBy:

```
>>> df2 = df.groupBy("_1")
>>> type(df2)
<class 'pyspark.sql.group.GroupedData'>
>>>
```

In order to use schema, you'll need first to define it:
see: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html

A schema sample can be found below (you'll need to add fields, and update names, type in order to adopt it to your case)

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema = StructType([
    StructField("F1", StringType(), True),
    StructField("F2", StringType(), True),
    StructField("F3", StringType(), True),
    StructField("F4", StringType(), True)])
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
```

Afterwards you'll be able to run it with schema:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(lines1,schema)
```

And now, you'll have names for the fields:

```
df.show()
+-------------+----+---+-----------------+
|           F1|  F2| F3|               F4|
+-------------+----+---+-----------------+
| 1472128348.0|HTTP|  -|  tr.vwt.gsf.asfh|
|1472237494.63|HTTP|  -|  tr.sdf.sff.sdfg|
|1473297794.26|HTTP|  -| tr.asfr.gdfg.sdf|
| 1474589345.0|HTTP|  -|tr.sdgf.gdfg.gdfg|
| 1472038475.0|HTTP|  -|  tr.sdf.csgn.sdf|
+-------------+----+---+-----------------+
```

in order to save it to CSV, you'll need to use "to_pandas()" , and "to_csv()"
(part of python pandas)

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

```
df.toPandas().to_csv('mycsv.csv')
```

the content of the csv file:

```
cat mycsv.csv

,F1,F2,F3,F4
0,1472128348.0,HTTP,-,tr.vwt.gsf.asfh
1,1472237494.63,HTTP,-,tr.sdf.sff.sdfg
2,1473297794.26,HTTP,-,tr.asfr.gdfg.sdf
3,1474589345.0,HTTP,-,tr.sdgf.gdfg.gdfg
4,1472038475.0,HTTP,-,tr.sdf.csgn.sdf
```

Note that you can cast a column using ".cast()", e.g. casting F1 to be of type float - adding a new column with type float, and dropping the old column)

```
df = df.withColumn("F1float", df["F1"].cast("float")).drop("F1")
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! This worked! BTW when I use schema, for StructField "FloatType" writes only null values. StringType has no issues. But do you know why FloatType copies null to my excel sheet?

Comment: when I've updated my schema to use "FloatType" on F1, I got the following error: "TypeError: FloatType can not accept object in type <type 'unicode'>". I'm not sure why it was identify as unicode. see update in my answer regarding ".cast()"

Comment: When i did the casting, no new column was added but old F1 was dropped.

Comment: try the following: before the casting: df.show(), casting: df = df.withColumn("F1float", df["F1"].cast("float")) , after the casting: df.show() - let me know if a new column was added

Comment: Hi.. i tried that. Now there is a new column added. But the new column has only 1 value repeated through out unlike F1 which had a variety of values. Seems like some conversion happened and only one value (which isn't present in F1) has been added.